# $addToSet / $set does not push the ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, set, strapi

Currently using Strapi v3.5.3ce. I have a post model with has relation with category model.

A post already exist, but I want to update the post with multiple categories, so I thought of using `$addToSet` / `$set` in order to eliminate duplicates added.

But it doesn't seem to push.

ways I have tried are

```
// with $set
const up = {
  $set: { categories: [ '6073ac8f68f6971f3edfc898', '6073ac8f68f888f3edfc111' ] },
  ...update
}

// with $addToSet
const up = {
  $addToSet: { categories: [ '6073ac8f68f6971f3edfc898', '6073ac8f68f888f3edfc111' ] },
  ...update
}

// with $addToSet and $each
const up = {
  $addToSet: { categories: { $each: [ '6073ac8f68f6971f3edfc898', '6073ac8f68f888f3edfc111' ] } },
  ...update
}


const post = await strapi.query('post').model
  .findOneAndUpdate({_id: 'blahblahblah'}, up, { new: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'categories',
    select: 'name'
  });
```

the above uses `findOneAndUpdate` but I have also tried using `update` / `updateOne`

None of the above worked, anyone has any idea what I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: third try should work, i think you are missing something else, just verify _id is present or not in collection and check db connection with right server and collection name.

Comment: @turivishal I did try those too.  Went into strapi admin dashbord copied the category id straight from there.  see the `...update` that's actually updating the `title` field to really make sure I am not modifying the wrong `post`, so anyways `title` does get updated but not category